# Android Asynchronous Http Client with(inside) a Service

Tags: android, http

I need to create powerfull SYNC Rest system Android <--> Server.
I choose that way: 
1) Create a Service 
2) Loop the service
3) Inside loop create requests (using Android Asynchronous Http Client by James Smith)

**But request doesnt work** 
Another way use Subsequent request(s) but this library doesnt support it, perhaps I'm wrong.

```
   @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) { 

        loopThread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    do {    
                        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                         client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                             @Override
                             public void onStart() {
                                 Log.v("Mad Service", "onStart");
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onSuccess(String response) {
                                 Log.v("Mad Service", "onSuccess");
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
                                 Log.v("Mad Service", "onFailure");
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onFinish() {
                                 Log.v("Mad Service", "onFinish");
                             }
                         });



                    } while(mQuit == false);


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        loopThread.start();
    }
```

Comment: **what does 'doesn't work' even means?** also, i don't see the point of asynchronous requests from within a thread? or did you understood the concept behind asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, Iunderstand, but Can I use this library as Subsequent request(s)?

Comment: what would subsequent mean in this context?

Comment: using THIS http library...I dont want change it :(

Comment: or why I cant start a request inside thread?

Comment: its mean I don't see Log.v(...) in my LogCat

Comment: you are using ASYNCHRONOUS requests. it means it is executed in a separated thread, meaning it is not blocking, meaning typically your thread is launching thousands of requests at the same time. which makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: sorry, I delete "sleep(1 * 60 * 1000)",  every 1 min  we makes request.
I tested 2min ago, async request with AQuery lib, all works.
But I need to know: is Async Lib(from title) can works in service in async mode or  subsequent?

Comment: you'd rather use a handler and post messages than have a thread sleep for 1 minute. with this library, since it is asynchronous, you can make your calls on the UI thread. It is even recommended, since the callbacks will occur on the calling thread.

Comment: usually yes, but in this case I need to provide all sync in background of app: server <-> service <-> DB

Comment: yes. and? you start your service, in the start command, you launch the first request, in the onSuccess, onFailure or onFinish, whichever comes first, you send a message to a handler in a minute, in the handler you launch the next request

Comment: client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {} - this REQUEST doesnt work in general inside service, no one steps: onStart()... doesnt show to us any info.
I made copy=paste code to UI, works without problems.

Comment: Thanks for disscusion , I will try some another http lib.

Comment: Lib works, but without loop and sleep(), thx